# Required dependencies not updating

Tags: php, composer-php, version, versioning

I'm updating some packages with `composer`. I'm using Laravel5.6 in my project.

The one that I'm trying is [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan) to version `0.10.7`. My current version is `0.9.2`.

### The problem

When I try to update, it shows a success message, but when checking the `outdate` packages output, it is still OUTDATED.

### What I've tried

Using `composer why-not phpstan/phpstan 0.10.7` gave me the following output:

```
laravel/laravel  my-branch-test  requires (for development)  phpstan/phpstan (^0.9.2)                      
phpstan/phpstan  0.10.7          requires                    nikic/php-parser (^4.0.2)                     
laravel/laravel  my-branch-test  does not require            nikic/php-parser (but v3.1.5 is installed)    
phpstan/phpstan  0.10.7          requires                    phpstan/phpdoc-parser (^0.3)                  
laravel/laravel  my-branch-test  does not require            phpstan/phpdoc-parser (but 0.2 is installed)
```

Then I tried to update `nikic/php-parser` and `phpdoc-parser` and re-run `composer update phpstan/phpstan` but it gave me the same result of before. (not updating)

**UPDATE**: running `composer update phpstan/phpstan --with-dependencies` gave me the following output:(but still didn't updated phpstan)

```
composer update phpstan/phpstan --with-dependencies
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                              
Package operations: 0 installs, 11 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating ocramius/package-versions (1.2.0 => 1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/finder (v4.1.4 => v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.9.0 => v1.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating jean85/pretty-package-versions (1.1 => 1.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating nette/utils (v2.4.9 => v2.5.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating nette/php-generator (v3.0.2 => v3.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Updating nette/neon (v2.4.2 => v2.4.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating nette/di (v2.4.10 => v2.4.14): Loading from cache
  - Updating nette/bootstrap (v2.4.5 => v2.4.6): Loading from cache
  - Updating nette/finder (v2.4.1 => v2.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating nette/robot-loader (v3.0.3 => v3.1.0): Loading from cache
Package sebastian/git is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
Discovered Package: caffeinated/modules
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: jenssegers/agent
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer
Discovered Package: rcrowe/twigbridge
Package manifest generated successfully.
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
```

### Code

In my `composer.json` file, the package is listed as:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.9.2",
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please try `composer update phpstan/phpstan --with-dependencies` and show the full command output if it doesn't help?

Comment: Ofc @xabbuh, see my updated answer.

Comment: Can you do the same but with `composer require --dev phpstan/phpstan:^0.10 --update-with-dependencies` instead?

Comment: Same result with this aproach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that others packages that I was using were using the `nikic/php-parser` package too, but considering only non-breaking changes (`nikic/php-parser":"^3.0"`), "blocking" the upgrade to `> 4.0`.

Because of composer [can't install two versions of the same package](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2167#issuecomment-22493709), my solution was not updating `phpstan` for now.

I will wait for the libs that require `nikic/php-parser` to update their requirements to `4.0` and up or will change these packages in the future.